# $http POST not returning correct response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, http-post, angularjs-http

The issue I'm having is that $http POST is not returning the correct response.
The data I require is stored under **config** instead of **data**

The Http POST request:

```
for (var i = 0; i < filmService.filmData.length; i++) {
      filmData.push({
        title     :    filmService.filmData[i].title,
        overview  :    filmService.filmData[i].info,
        poster    :    filmService.filmData[i].poster,
        genres    :    filmService.filmData[i].genres,
        release   :    filmService.filmData[i].release

      }); 
}
  var data = angular.toJson(filmData[0]);


     $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url:'/search',
            data: data,
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
          },
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log(response); //response received
    });
```

The **response** I got in the console - highlighted in RED is the data I need:

[image: The part highlighted in RED is the data I need but its in CONFIG.]

Comment: It looks like you've highlighted the data you sent from the client--your filmData object, the thing that you posted. The other data on your response object looks like the actual server response. (Of course I don't know what you expect this API to return.)

Comment: Yeah, the documentation explains it. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http The 'config' property is just the original request parameters.

Comment: @georgeawg the issue lied on server side, and thanks that issue has also been amended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this and you should get what you want:

```
  $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url:'/search',
        data: data,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
      },
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        var data = response.data
        console.log(data); //response received
});
```

Comment: Hi @Ohjay44, that doesn't seem to work, it only gives me the values in (data: id and release).  I want the values in (config: > data:) highlighted in red.

Comment: Config is what you are sending not what you are receiving. You are only receiving id and release from the server. On your server side code make sure you are returning all of the data you need,

Comment: @Yacub you already have those values--you constructed that data yourself.

Comment: it seems the data is not being passed over to the server.

Comment: Can you show some of your server side code? response.data will be all of the data that you send back from the server.

Comment: On the server side, i have this:                                                      app.post('/search', function (req, res) {

 console.log(req.body);

}); but it returns undefined on the terminal.

Comment: Can you please edit your code to show the server side code and explain which framework you are using. Ex: Nodejs with Express

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to require body-parser on my app. which is why I was not getting any results over to the server. Thanks for the help @Ohjay44! and @struthersneil!

Comment: That is what I was suspecting! Glad I could help.

Answer (score -1):

Inside your `.then` function return the config.data.

The result will be like this

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url:'/search',
        data: data,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
      },
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        var data = response.config.data
        console.log(data); //response received
});
```

Comment: Config is what you are sending not receiving.